# CipherOutputStream causes IllegalBlockSizeException on receiving message

Tags: java, encryption

I'm writing server/client system that uses AES.
The following method (server side) works fine:

```
    public static byte[] encode(byte type, byte subType, String string, Cipher cipher) 
    throws NullPointerException, IOException {
        
        Objects.requireNonNull(string);
        Objects.requireNonNull(cipher);
                
        byte[] data = null;
        
        try {
            data = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {};
        
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bytesOutput.write(type);
        bytesOutput.write(subType);
        bytesOutput.write(data);
        
        byte[] plainBytes = bytesOutput.toByteArray();
        byte[] bytes = null;
        
        try {
            bytes = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
                
        return base64Bytes; 
    }
```

But when I replaced it with the following code I got IllegalBlockSizeException on client side.

```
public static byte[] encode(byte type, byte subType, String string, Cipher cipher) 
throws NullPointerException, EncodingException {
                
        Objects.requireNonNull(string);
        Objects.requireNonNull(cipher);
                
        byte[] data = null;
                
        try {
            data = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {};

        CipherOutputStream cipherOutput = null;

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            OutputStream base64Output = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(bytesOutput);
            cipherOutput = new CipherOutputStream(base64Output, cipher);
            cipherOutput.write(type);
            cipherOutput.write(subType);
            cipherOutput.write(data);
            cipherOutput.flush();
                    
            byte[] bytes = bytesOutput.toByteArray();
            
            return bytes;

        } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
            throw new EncodingException(e);

        } finally {

            if (cipherOutput != null)
                try {
                    cipherOutput.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {};
            }
        }
}
```

What is wrong with second method? Both methods use the same cipher. Nothing changed on server excluding the encode method.

Comment: You have to close the CipherOutputStream *before* you extract the bytes from the ByteOutputStream. Only in the close() method is the cipher object finalized. Also, by doing so you'll substantially simplify your exception handling.

Comment: Thanks! Tested  - it works.

Comment: And if you want to use even less error handling, replace `UTF_8.name()` by just `UTF_8`.